# Open csv without any data change/formatting

Tags: csv, libreoffice

I have some csv file which contains data like this `0234`

When I open that csv,   my libreoffice  automatically converts value like `234` (leading zero removed)

libreoffice also formats some large numbers, so instead of original values i'm getting like: `13323+15`

Question: can I somehow set-up libreoffice like so, that it never changed original values and opened file without any auto formatting ?

Comment: "never" is a bad word, never say "never". One day you will need to open a file with automatic conversion, and you have already destroyed this feature. Your problem is very easy to solve. In the import filter settings window from the text, simply select the columns that should not be changed (click on the column heading) and select the text field type from the drop-down list. I'm talking about using the settings in this [**window**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/65667/importing-english-numbers-into-a-german-spreadsheet/).

Comment: @JohnSUN - oh, thats really helpful, i was looking for this setting exactly.